# How to transform an primal MILP to dual MILP without violating constraints role

Tags: computer-science, linear-programming

I have a primal MILP with some constraints related to the specific structure of an optimization problem I am solving.

Basically, it involves the combination of two decision variables `A[u,x] and B[u,v,x,y]` where B is the well know multi commodity flow variable. The constraint is written as follows :

```
A[u,x] + A[v,y] <= B[u,v,x,y] -Constraint 1
```

I would like to know if moving to a dual MILP, constraint 1 will not have its role as in the primal program ? If yes, how one should deal with this issue and come up with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is the dual of a MIP model?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to come up with a dual of my MIP in order to apply the primal dual algorithm. So far, I only know what is a primal model :). Not even sure if it exists in this form. Any clarifications are very appreciated @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: There is no such thing as the dual of a MIP (at least not in way LPs have a dual).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen So should I relax it and get the LP to go for the primal dual algorithm then ? thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have an optimization problem involving three objective functions where the core of the problem involves the combination of two decision variables that are defined to deal with the feature of the problem iteself. I want to develop a randomized algorithm to approximate the optimal solution. I am investigating primal dual algorithm. So far, I have the primal I need the dual to apply the primal dual framework. Does it make sense to you @ErwinKalvelagen ? Thank you for your time and reply :).

Comment: For what it is worth: Primal-dual LP/MOLP methods don't solve MIP/MOIP problems.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen could you please point me out to some references saying that because I need to justify it in front of my supervisor. Thanks